# Extract values from a string in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How to get a value from a string e.g

```
search_params[:price] = "1460,4500"
```

How can I get the first number into one variable and second into a different variable?

Comment: `v1, v2 = search_params[:price].scan /\d+/ #=> ["1460", "4500"]` is one way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean this??:

```
first_price, second_price = search_params[:price].split(',')
```

Comment: I am glad it helped you. If an answer helps you on stackoverflow then kindly accept it by clicking on the check icon on the left side of the answer.

Comment: will do, it says I have to wait for 10 mins

Answer (score 0):

You can use [split method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-split)

```
irb(main):002:0> price = "1460,4500"
=> "1460,4500"
irb(main):003:0> price.split(',')
=> ["1460", "4500"]
irb(main):004:0> a, b = price.split(',')
=> ["1460", "4500"]
irb(main):005:0> a
=> "1460"
irb(main):006:0> b
=> "4500"
```

Comment: You answer was been given by @Surya earlier.